# How to clear easyui combobox input on click

Tags: jquery, events, combobox, onclick, jquery-easyui

How to clear easyui combobox input on click? 
Looked for onClick event on editor but didn't find.
Tried to bind event on input class but didn't work.

Comment: Mention what you have tried so far...

Comment: I guess [that](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combobox.php) link would help :)

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. Everything I tried was removed from code so I couldn't show what has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combo box isn't created until after the DOM is rendered, so you have to use event delegation to target its focus and blur events

```
$("body").on("focus", "input.combo-text", function(){
    $(this).data("prev-value", this.value);
    this.value = "";
})
.on("blur", "input.combo-text", function(){
    if ($(this).val() === ""){
        $(this).val($(this).data("prev-value"));
    }
    $(this).data("prev-value", "");
});
```

As you can see, when the input receives focus, we are storing the previous value as a data attribute on the element, then retrieving it when focus is lost if the user didn't input anything different.

**[Demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/combo-box-demo/demo/combobox/basic.html)**